# "Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item."

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-photos-api

I'm trying to upload a photo on Google Photos, with google api, but i always get this error:

```
"status":{"code":3,"message":"Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item."}}
```

I think that the problem is in the way i take the binary data of photo.

In this code i follow google photo api developers documentation, and it says, after take authorization, to:
1- Upload the raw bytes to a Google Server: to take upload-token
2- Use the upload token to create the media item.

This my node js code:

```
const photo = fs.readFileSync("fbimages/"+req.session.id_client+"/Prague/2020-05-30T17:29:14+0000_0.png", {
            'encoding': 'binary',
            'flag' : 'r'
        });


 var url= 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads';
 var headers= {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
     'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
     'X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type': 'image/png',
     'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol': 'raw',
     'X-Goog-Upload-File-Name': "2020-05-30T17:29:14+0000_0.png",
 };
 var body= photo

 request({
      url: url,
      method:'POST',
      headers: headers,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }, function(error, response, body1){
      if(error)
      {
        console.log(error);
      }
      else
      {
         var upToken = body1.toString();

         console.log(upToken);

         var url= 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate';
         var headers= {
             'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+token,
             'Content-type': 'application/json',
         };
         var body= {
             'newMediaItems': [
                 {
                   'description': 'Prague',
                   'simpleMediaItem': {
                         'fileName': 'prova',
                         'uploadToken': upToken,
                    }
                 }
             ]
         };
         request({
             url: url,
             method: 'POST',
             headers: headers,
             rejectUnauthorized: false,
             body: JSON.stringify(body),

           }, function(error, response, body){
              if(error)
              {
                 console.log(error);
               }
               else
               {
                  res.send(JSON.parse(body));
                }
          });
   }});
```

Please help me, if anyone has any idea!!

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- I think that `encoding: "binary"` is not required.

  - In this case, ``const photo = fs.readFileSync("fig1.png", { flag: "r" });`and`const photo = fs.readFileSync("fig1.png");` can be used.
- Please modify `body: JSON.stringify(body)` to `photo` of `const photo = fs.readFileSync("fig1.png", { flag: "r" });`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
const photo = fs.readFileSync("fbimages/"+req.session.id_client+"/Prague/2020-05-30T17:29:14+0000_0.png", {
            'encoding': 'binary',
            'flag' : 'r'
        });


 var url= 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads';
 var headers= {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
     'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
     'X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type': 'image/png',
     'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol': 'raw',
     'X-Goog-Upload-File-Name': "2020-05-30T17:29:14+0000_0.png",
 };
 var body= { 'media-binary-data': photo }

 request({
      url: url,
      method:'POST',
      headers: headers,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }, function(error, response, body1){
```

To:

```
const photo = fs.readFileSync("fbimages/"+req.session.id_client+"/Prague/2020-05-30T17:29:14+0000_0.png", { flag: "r" });

var url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads";
var headers = {
  Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
  "Content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type": "image/png",
  "X-Goog-Upload-Protocol": "raw",
  "X-Goog-Upload-File-Name": "2020-05-30T17:29:14+0000_0.png",
};

request(
  {
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    body: photo,
  },
  function (error, response, body1) {
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your `token` can be used for this API. Please be careful this.
- When you want to directly put the uploaded image to an alubmn, please include `albumId` for requesting to `https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate`.

#### Reference:

- [Upload media](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I resolve with: 
`var file = fs.readFileSync("fbimages/"+req.session.id_client+"/"+titolo+"/"+foto, 'binary');
        var photo = Buffer.from(file, 'binary');`